# Concat doesn't work properly in files in java

Tags: java, file-browser

I have to do a project without the swing library.I have to browse over the files and was trying to do something like this:

```
fichero = new File(fichero.getAbsolutePath().concat("\\" + str));
```

where `str` is the new Directory that you want to access

Hope someone could help me. 
Thank you

Comment: What is the result you get? What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
fichero = new File(fichero.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + str);
```

or

```
fichero = new File(fichero.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + str);
```

or

```
fichero = new File(fichero.getAbsolutePath().concat("/").concat(str);
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `\\` or you may use a `/`. I suggest you use the latter as it is platform independent.

Also, use the constructor:

```
File(String parent, String child)
```

The docs say:

> Creates a new File instance from a parent pathname string and a child
>   pathname string. If parent is null then the new File instance is
>   created as if by invoking the single-argument File constructor on the
>   given child pathname string.
>
> Otherwise the parent pathname string is taken to denote a directory,
>   and the **child pathname string is taken to denote either a directory or
>   a file.** If the child pathname string is absolute then it is converted
>   into a relative pathname in a system-dependent way. If parent is the
>   empty string then the new File instance is created by converting child
>   into an abstract pathname and resolving the result against a
>   system-dependent default directory. Otherwise each pathname string is
>   converted into an abstract pathname and the child abstract pathname is
>   resolved against the parent.

So, your code should look like:

```
fichero = new File(fichero.getAbsolutePath(),str);
```

*NB: You may also use the `File` constructor that accepts a `File` and `String` as an argument, thus eliminating the call to `getAbsolutePath()`*